# Bundling C++ extension headers with a Python package source distribution

Tags: python, packaging, python-extensions, python-packaging

I'm writing a Cython wrapper to a C++ library that I would like to distribute as a Python package. I've come up with a dummy version of my package that looks like this (full source [here](https://github.com/standage/packagetest)).

```
$ tree
.
├── bogus.pyx
├── inc
│   └── bogus.hpp
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── bogus.cpp
$
$ cat inc/bogus.hpp 
#ifndef BOGUS
#define BOGUS

class bogus
{
protected:
    int data;

public:
    bogus();
    int get_double(int value);
};

#endif
$
$ cat src/bogus.cpp 
#include "bogus.hpp"

bogus::bogus() : data(0)
{

}

int bogus::get_double(int value)
{
    data = value * 2;
    return data;
}
$ cat bogus.pyx 
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = src/bogus.cpp
# cython: c_string_type=str, c_string_encoding=ascii

cdef extern from 'bogus.hpp':
    cdef cppclass bogus:
        bogus() except +
        int get_double(int value)

cdef class Bogus:
    cdef bogus b
    def get_double(self, int value):
        return self.b.get_double(value)
```

With the following `setup.py` file, I can can confirm that the library installs correctly with `python setup.py install` and that it works correctly.

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import glob

headers = list(glob.glob('inc/*.hpp'))

bogus = Extension(
    'bogus',
    sources=['bogus.pyx', 'src/bogus.cpp'],
    include_dirs=['inc/'],
    language='c++',
    extra_compile_args=['--std=c++11', '-Wno-unused-function'],
    extra_link_args=['--std=c++11'],
)

setup(
    name='bogus',
    description='Troubleshooting Python packaging and distribution',
    author='Daniel Standage',
    ext_modules=[bogus],
    install_requires=['cython'],
    version='0.1.0'
)
```

However, when I build a source distribution using `python setup.py sdist build`, the C++ header files are not included and the C++ extension cannot be compiled.

**How can I make sure the C++ header files get bundled with the source distribution?!?!**

<rant>

Troubleshooting this has uncovered a tremendously convoluted and inconsistent mess of documentation, suggestions, and hacks, none of which have worked for me. Put a `graft` line in `MANIFEST.in`? Nope. The `package_data` or `data_files` options? Nope. Python packaging seems to have improved a lot in the last few years, but it is still nigh impenetrable for those of us that don't live and breathe Python packaging!

</rant>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Put `include inc/*.hpp` in the `MANIFEST.in` file.

### Long answer

Based on various blog posts and SO threads, I had tried the suggestion of declaring the files in a `MANIFEST.in` file. Following [these instructions](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html), I added a `graft inc/` line to `MANIFEST.in` to include the entire directory. This did not work.

However, replacing this line with `include inc/*.hpp` did work. Arguably this should have been the first thing I tried, but being unfamiliar with the intricacies and warts of setuptools and distutils, I had no reason to expect that `graft` wouldn't work.